# How to get/parse HTML string for a cell value in excelJS?

Tags: node.js, exceljs

I am trying to read an excel file where cells have formatting like Bold, Italic, Underline using exceljs library. I want to store the values in the cell as html but when I try to use `r.html` - it says html does not exist. Please check the attachment image. I would like to get output like `<strong>Hello</strong>` . How can I achieve this.

```
const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
    const worksheet = await workbook.xlsx.readFile(
      "../src/controllers/Formatted.xlsx"
    );



const rows = worksheet.getWorksheet("Sheet1").getRows(1, 3);
    rows?.forEach((row) =>
      console.log(row?.eachCell((r) => console.log(r.value, r.type)))
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of documentation mangling, I found ExcelJS provides the `Font` property for each cell, which returns an object which maintains booleans for bold, italics and other styles.

For each cell in `.xlsx` file, we need to parse the HTML from the `Font` property and generate an HTML string for that cell content.

Below is the snippet for converting formatted excel cell contents to HTML string.

It supports styles like - Bold, Italic, Underline, Strikethrough.

```
const convertFontToHTML = (
  text: string,
  font?: Partial<ExcelJS.Font>
): string[] => {
  return [
    font?.bold ? "<strong>" : "",
    font?.italic ? "<em>" : "",
    font?.underline ? "<u>" : "",
    font?.strike ? "<s>" : "",
    text,
    font?.strike ? "</s>" : "",
    font?.underline ? "</u>" : "",
    font?.italic ? "</em>" : "",
    font?.bold ? "</strong>" : "",
  ];
};

const combineTags = (str: string): string => {
  // simple tag combining where possible
  return str
    .replace(/<\/strong><strong>/g, "")
    .replace(/<\/em><em>/g, "")
    .replace(/<\/u><u>/g, "")
    .replace(/<\/s><s>/g, "");
};
```

Feel free to comment if any better solution exists :)